# TableView Cell Error - iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i have this error when run the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

I do not understand, I have correctly assigned the identifier id but by mistake ..

**This is my code:**

*When override the fun cellForRowAtIndexPath:*

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellDataflow") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = "This is a title."
        return cell
}
```

And here is where i call the view:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   ….more code…
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MainTVC(), animated: true)

}
```

N.B. => I call this way the new view because I have a custom cell, and I could not call it from the storyboard.

Thanks

EDIT: The error in in the line:

> let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellDataflow")
>   as UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you also need the index path ?

So:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IDENTIFIER", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Swift expert but I checked the documentation, the method returns an optional value:

```
func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String) -> AnyObject?
```

Perhaps it is returning `nil`, try using `as?` instead of `as` and check for `nil`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. 
but it is not. 

Among the various tests I realized that I recall hurt the new view. 

I try to explain my establishment: 
- I have a list with a customized cell. when I tap on the cell I want you to go on a new view with a list, but this time the cell is not custom. 

maybe the wrong call, because it seems that always works on the old view when I go on the class MainTVC

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "always works on the old view".

Answer (score -1):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

I think this will help you...